# Does Cassandra preserve writetime after a restore?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I would like to know if a query like

```
select id,field,writetime(field) from mykeyspace.table
```

will return exactly the same values after a backup/restore operation. I'm not sure if the restore operation will change the internal timestamp handled by Cassandra's "writetime" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "writetime" is preserved across Cassandra backup/restore. It can be easily tested if you had TTL on your original data. While you restore, the TTL gets carried from original written time and not the restore time.

Say for testing, you had a short TTL of 5min and you did a backup/restore, the record would get wiped out within 5min of original writetime.